# Convert .NET data format ro Excel column format

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataformat

I need convert my grid columns format to version MS Excel version.
I've written code converting popular numeric formats (eg N0,N2 etc) but my interface provides option for end user to specify any data format in .NET 'style'.

Before I spend hours coding trying to cover all possible formats Id like to check with you guys if you possibly dont have something similar you can share, or maybe there is some source code I can adapt

Here is how Im doing it now:

```
if (colFormat=="N2") xlsFormat = "# ##0,00";
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Export your grid to excel?

Comment: Indeed. I'm already doing that in fact

Comment: Are you using any third party grid component?

Comment: Yes. Infragistics. This component allows to format cells but in excel style formatting not c#

Comment: I don't know the Infragistics components. But I would assume other Infragistics users have solved this problem already. Maybe asking them or Infragistics themselves is more helpful. Sorry.

Comment: I googled before posting here. Problem is not infragistics specific. This is dot net to excel translation